# How do you print out one element from a two element list, while retaining brackets and quotes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is the list:

```
[ [ "First", "A" ], [ "Second", "B" ] ]
```

Right now I am using:

```
"#{list[0]} is the first element"
```

Which returns:

```
"firsta is the first element"
```

I would like it to return:

```
["First", "A"] is the first element
```

Full code:

```
set1 = list[0].last.downcase
set2 = list[1].last.downcase
if set1.eql?(set2)
   "#{list[0]} is the first element"
elseif
   #to-do
else
   #to-do
end
```

Also, I am using the online interpreter from labs.codecademy.com (Ruby 1.8.7).

Comment: Can you post the full program code?  I'm trying this in IRB and it gives me the desired result, I'm not sure how you're seeing "firsta is the first element".

Comment: He is using ruby 1.8 I suppose

Answer (score 3):

You're using Ruby 1.8 and you're seeing 1.8's version of [`Array#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-to_s):

> **to_s → string**
>
> Returns `self.join`.
>
> ```
> [ "a", "e", "i", "o" ].to_s   #=> "aeio"
> ```

Using [Ruby 1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-to_s) would give you the output you're expecting:

> **to_s()**
>
> *Alias for: `inspect`*

but you can use `inspect` yourself in 1.8:

```
1.8.7 >> list = [ [ "First", "A" ], [ "Second", "B" ] ]
=> [["First", "A"], ["Second", "B"]]
1.8.7 >> list[0].to_s
=> "FirstA"
1.8.7 >> "#{list[0].inspect} is the first element"
=> "["First", "A"] is the first element"
```